# Does relativistic length contraction mean the acceleration throughout the material was not uniform?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light

If a black hole accelerates a hypothetical stick near the speed of ligth the stick will tend to reduce its length but does it mean that if the distance between atoms of that stick changed, accelerations of different parts of the stick were of different?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the rod will experience different accelerations at different points even regardless of length contraction. As the atoms in the rod are not infinitely rigid, it will take time for force to propagate through it between different points within it. As such, if one end is pulled, it will take some short but nonzero time for the other end to accelerate as well. Hope this helps!